# Can LVS+Ldirectord load balancing serve two domains?

Tags: load-balancing

I have a Load Balancing cluster with two real servers using Direct routing method, there's one domain on the real servers. Now, I only set one virtual IP and two real IP for ldirectord. How to add another virtual IP and two real IPs for different domain? Is it possible? Thank you.

My current ldirectord configuration looks like follows:

```
# /etc/ha.d/ldirectord.cf
checktimeout=3
checkinterval=5
autoreload=yes
logfile="/var/log/ldirectord.log"
quiescent=yes
virtual=192.168.0.200:80
    fallback=127.0.0.1:80
    real=192.168.0.110:80 gate
    real=192.168.0.120:80 gate
    service=http
    request="test.html"
    receive="Still alive"
    scheduler=wlc
    protocol=tcp
    checktype=negotiate
```

I was following this instruction:

http://www.novell.com/communities/node/4846/load-balancing-howto-lvs-ldirectord-heartbeat-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `virtual` section, and all the associated bits to support it, just like your first one.  The rest of the direct routing setup is, naturally, the same.